# Confidence Interval For Values

Tags: confidence-interval, tolerance-interval

Confidence Intervals help construct a range where you expect the true mean of a population of values to be, given some arbitrary sample. I'm curious if there is an equivalent function you can use, when given only a sample set of data to determine the probability that any value is in a set range. For example, a method of determining that there is a 95% chance for any value in the population to be between 5 and 10 (in other words, 95% of the population samples are between 5 and 10).

Comment: This sounds like a *tolerance interval.*  One ordinarily doesn't refer to a "95% chance," but instead characterizes the interval as one that is likely to include 95% of the population.  Is that what you mean?  Or are you asking about an estimate of the full range of the population; *viz.,* an interval that has at least a 95% chance of including *every* value in the population?

Comment: @whuber Thanks, added some clarity.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for this. After looking up tolerance intervals I realized that they are exactly what I was looking for. And just to clarify, if you construct a tolerance interval with 99% certainty that a range holds 90% of the population, is it implied that that means at least 90% of the population? If not then I don't think I understand them entirely. Why else would the range of a tolerance interval increase when the certainty level increases?

Comment: That's correct: it's ok for the interval to include more than 90% of the population.  There are forms of tolerance intervals that are constructed to contain (say) 90% of the population *on average,* but their use is rare (in my experience).

Comment: @whuber Okay thank you for clarifying. I appreciate all the help you've been.